# Concatenating only filled cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, concatenate

I currently have a spreadsheet to keep track of scores in a card game.  There can be between two and five players.  I have the following:

```
| Players  |
|----------|
| Dave     |
| Paul     |
| John     |
|          |
|          |
```

At the moment I use:

```
= JOIN( " vs " ; C10:C14 )
```

But the problem is I then end up with `Dave vs Paul vs John vs vs`.

Is there a way to make it say `Dave vs Paul vs John` but if I had more players, `Dave vs Paul vs John vs Rob` with one formula?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992):

```
=textjoin(" vs ",1,C10:C14)
```

The second parameter is set to 1 indicating that empty cells should be ignored. Zero will include those empty cells.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's shorter, simpler and allows you to ignore blank values.

Comment: I always read everything to look for the best answer not just a "working answer" :)

Comment: The middle argument is the boolean "Ignore_empty" so could perhaps more properly be written `=TEXTJOIN(" vs ", TRUE, C10:C14)`.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, by `FILTER`ing the array:

```
= JOIN( " vs " ; FILTER(C10:C14; NOT(C10:C14 = "") ))
```

Thus, the `JOIN` method will only operate on non-empty cells.

I have set up an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdGNQS3NZc3Q0bV9CM1BSQTMyOS1OMVE&usp=sharing).

Also, check the [Google Spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs) (search for `FILTER`).

Answer (score 6):

Both of the solutions above work if there is at least one cell containing text.  However:

```
= JOIN(" vs ",SPLIT(JOIN("%",C10:C14),"%",0))
```

Would return `%%%%` if C10:C14 were all empty and.

```
= JOIN( " vs " ; FILTER(C10:C14; NOT(C10:C14 = "") ))
```

Would return `#N/A` if C10:C14 were all empty.

However, you can slightly amend the first solution to replace the `%` signs with empty strings by wrapping the formula with the `SUBSTITUTE` function like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
   JOIN(" vs ",SPLIT(JOIN("%",C10:C14),"%",0)),    // text_to_search
   "%",                                            // search_for
   ""                                              // replace_with
 )
```

<sub>(Shown on multiple lines for clarity)</sub>

Comment: Please note: "above" really has no context in answers, since answers can be sorted in different ways.

Answer (score 4):

I've found another solution:

```
=JOIN(" vs ",SPLIT(JOIN("%",C10:C14),"%",0))
```

The % can be any symbol really that isn't present in the list, like a comma, or ampersand, or question mark.

Answer (score 0):

textjoin(" vs ", true, C10:C14)
true means here that if cell is empty, then ignore

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! I think this is already mentioned in this answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/109594/136642