# Concatenating two columns using only filled cells in one of them

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In my table, column A has row names and other columns have values:

```
+------+---+
| M100 | D |
| M130 | B |
| M340 |   |
| P304 | F |
| P400 |   |
| P499 | C |
+------+---+
```

I'd like to join nonempty values, preceding them with row names and separating by commas. So, the desired output is:

> M100A,M130B,P304A,P499C

This is somewhat similar to [Concatenating only filled cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40031/) except I also have row names.

If the `query` function allowed concatenation of string values, a solution could be something like `select concat(A,B) where B!=''`, subsequently joined. At present this is not supported, however.

---

I post my solution as an answer, but I'd like to see other approaches, as the double-filter formula looks a bit repetitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer

A formula that does the required in the question

```
=JOIN(",",
      QUERY(
            {ArrayFormula({A1:A6}&{B1:B6}),B1:B6},
            "Select Col1 Where Col2<>''"
      )
 )
```

## Explanation

The above formula has nested three functions, use the matrix handling feature of Google Sheets and the concatenate operator.

- `ArrayFormula({A1:A6}&{B1:B6})` : Concatenates the cell values of each row.
- `{ArrayFormula({A1:A6}&{B1:B6}),B1:B6}` : Creates a range with two columns. The second column will be used for filtering.
- `QUERY` is used to do the filtering.
- `JOIN` is used to create the string separating the elements with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a formula that does the above, line-broken and indented for readability:

```
=JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA( 
  FILTER($A2:$A7, NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B7))) & FILTER(B2:B7, NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B7)))
))
```

---

There is also a simpler formula, but it leaves a trailing comma in the result:

```
=CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(B2:B7="", "", $A2:$A7 & B2:B7 & ",")
))
```